# WCF service as a part of MVC application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a web application in MVC4. I'm going to host in on a **shared hosting** provider. I want to extend it with a WCF service for uploading files. (There will by a WPF desktop application that will allow users to upload files directly from their PCs.)

I'd rather host it somehow "together" to avoid problems with read/write access to storage directory, but I have no idea how to do this.

1. Should I host WCF as a selfhost in MVC app?
2. Should I make the WCF service an application or a class library?
3. How to tie it together with the MVC app?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally found how to make it work.

In your MVC app Web.config add:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

In your routes config ---> Global.asax or App_Start/RoutesConfig (depending on MVC version) add:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    ...
    routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("hello", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(YourServiceClass)));
    ...
}
```

And that's it. Now your service appears under localhost/hello or wherever you deploy your app.

This uses BasicHttpBinging by default. If you need other you have to implement your own ServiceHostFactory. From what I observed, this method only works for HTTP bindings. When I tried to add a NetTcpBinding it failed.

Comment: Side note: currently, it looks like a library used for Serviceroute, SOAcollective, was last updated in 2012 and the SOAcollective website is non-existent. An alternative is using SimpleInjector to get the above route configured.

Answer (score 3):

We do this all the time in the following way:

1. Create a WCF class library
2. Reference the WCF class library in your ASP.NET MVC 4 webapplication
3. Create a Svc file in your ASP.NET web app making the WCF endpoint available as such
4. Maybe you need to play a bit with the settings in the web.config file, which is now including WCF service endpoint settings next to the ASP.NET settings.

Comment: Can you post any link for the tutorial ??

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already building an MVC4 app, you might as well consider using MVC4 + Web API since those work together without any issues (Web API is previously known WCF REST).

If you still decide to stick with WCF, I wouldn't mix it in the same project with MVC4 application but rather host it as additional IIS application, side-by-side with MVC4.

Comment: "I wouldn't mix it in the same project with MVC4 application" Can you please explain why?

Comment: Mixing two pipelines that were not built to work together. It's really non-standard approach.

Comment: Are there any potential problems?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with hosting a wcf service in a web app. In fact, that is exactly what happens when you use IIS to host a WCF service.

Comment: Can you please explain pretension Aisadvantages/Advantages using the wcf inside MVC?