# How to deploy MVC and WCF applications together

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, deployment

I have WCF application and MVC application in 1 solution. When I deploy projects with WCF, I always deployed them like 2 sites. Firstly, I deployed WCF application to IIS, then MVC application and use WCF's endpoint address.

Is it possible to deploy MVC and WCF applications together, not like 2 separate site? WCF runs inside ASP application. And in IIS we have 1 site.

Comment: I have modified your title to give it some meaning, you should update your question also to include research effort

Comment: I think this solves your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351081/wcf-service-as-a-part-of-mvc-application