# Why is my WCF hosted in IIS not working unless I am debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, iis

I have hosted a WCF application in IIS on my local machine. The host name in IIS and host file is "serv.xxxx.local". My appl pool is running in IIS and my net.tcp Port Sharing Service is is also running in my Service.

However when i try to consume this wcf service from my MVC application, it doesnt work, unless I attach my WCF project to the process in Visual Studio.

Why can I just consume my WCF service without debugging in Visual Studios

I am running WINDOWS 10 by the way, i noticed there is no start automatically for the website in IIS.

Comment: can you trace the WCF url that your MVC app uses. I would guess you have a web.config file issue that stores the url.? Also if everything is local, why not try using localhost?

Comment: @ife labolz, Do you mean that it works well during debugging your WCF project, but not work if you run the web client? If so, I think Dhawalk's suggestion is correct, you need to check that whether you really configure the web.config correctly.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351081/wcf-service-as-a-part-of-mvc-application and http://blah.winsmarts.com/2008-4-Host_a_WCF_Service_in_IIS_7_-and-amp;_Windows_2008_-_The_right_way.aspx, of course, if you get any error messages, please also share it here.

Comment: @ife labolz,Could you run your client app now?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT i still cant, to clarify, i have hosted my WCF in IIS, and i usually run my project with a url like this serv.flee.local, that is a MVC application that makes a call to my WCF project. So for instance, when a user logs into that application from the url provided, it makes a service call to the WCF project, now this seems to only work when that WCF is in debug mode, so when i run the project from Visual studio. It shouldnt be the case since it is already hosted in IIS (both the mvc application and the wcf application), and the application pools are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with this was that the app pool configured for my WCF service did not have the access to my SQL Server database. I had to add the app pool the list of Logins in SQL Server.

To do this:

> 1) Open SQL Server
>
> 2) Expand the Security tree
>
> 3) Right click on "Logins"
>
> 4) Add your app pool. e.g "IIS AppPool\" and click OK,
>
> 5) Right click on the login you just created and click on Properties, then in the UserMappings tab, select the database you wish to access and then, select datareader and datawriter, click ok.

Everything should be fine after that.